# showing dynamic image in fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am collecting images from database for different categories and trying to show then on a button click as gallery.
 by default fancybox gallery is like:

```
$.fancybox.open([
    {
       href : '1_b.jpg',
       title : 'My title'
    }, {
       href : '2_b.jpg',
       title : '2nd title'
    }, {
       href : '3_b.jpg'
    }
]);
```

Now in place of all those static images i need to show images coming in a loop say a jquery each function,now how to do that?

Comment: paste your tried codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/////database connection in php

> ```
> $.fancybox.open([
> <?php
> $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery");
> $num=mysql_num_rows($sql);
> $count=0;
> while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
> ?>
>     {
>        href : '<?=$result['url']?>',
>        title : '<?=$result['my_title']?>'
>     }
> <?php
> $count++;
> if($count!=$num){
> echo ',';
> }////end of if
> }//// end of while
> ?>
> ]);
> ```